# If I want to use MOSS 2007 Single Sign-On, do my users HAVE TO be Active Directory users?

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on

I want to use MOSS 2007's single sign-on feature, but read that the server needs to be in an Active Directory environment. This I understand, but does this mean all my users HAVE TO be Active Directory users? Can I not use MOSS2007 Single Sign-on if my users are authenticated using Forms Authentication (using a custom membership provider?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you'd have to write your own [SSO provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.singlesignon.issoprovider.aspx). The default one only works with Windows identities.

Edit: There's a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566925.aspx) on MSDN for creating them, if you want to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

when i connect SP server with CS server using SSO, does the roles and user permissions for SP users transfered with the user, so if i created new sp user with read role, then i accessed cs server, i will find that a role created for that user in the cs with read permissions?